# htaccess rewrite rule with PHP GET variables causing 500 internal error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I've been attempting this: playerstats.php?player=Notch would result in www.example.com/Notch, yet the problem is every method I try it results in a 500 internal server error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\$ playerstats.php?player=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I'm using NGINX also if thats any concern

Comment: what is the error that apache is reporting?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ playerstats.php?player=$1 [L,QSA]
```